# Secure JavaScript Site Specific API

Tags: php, javascript, api

I have been thinking about how to do this for a while, and I am not sure what the best approach is for this.

What I want to do, is allow users to sign up their website, they then are given a javascript snippet with a key, code, and a link to a file stored on my server.

**Example**

```
<script>
    var prefix_key  = 1234567890;
    var prefix_code = "hfj48fj4587tgfj5trutjh47dl4gx04jd9f";
</script>
<script src="http://mysite.com/js/somefile.js"></script>
```

Now, what can happen is say I have that on my site, and you come and copy it to your site. How can I secure it so it doesn't work on your site but still works on mine?

**Note:** I will be using PHP as a back end if back end is needed.

Comment: You can use something like a token. Is the key url specific?

Comment: It is just domain specific.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `key` and `code` from an ajax request based on a fixed API code which is user specific.

For example:

Give you every user a fixed API code to query the page which returns `key` and `code`

```
http://mysite.com/some_page_to_get_the_key_and_code.php?apikey=243h325h2353
```

Comment: after that what would happen next? I would like to some how validate that they own the site that the code is on...

Comment: @RyanNaddy, Nobody will know key and code unless then have console window.

Comment: @RyanNaddy, Are you trying to create a Licensing system of your clients?

Comment: @RyanNaddy, JavaScript can be hacked this way or that. You should seek server solutions.